# How to sum row on postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.1

```
ID  pp1 pp2 pp3 pp4 pp5 Total
A   100 33  45  67  88
B   20  34  46  68  44
C   59  35  47  69  45
D   23  36  48  70  46
E   23  37  49  71  47
F   11  38  50  72  48
G   45  39  51  73  49
```

Above is a sample of my table
i just want to add a total column

```
ID  pp1 pp2 pp3 pp4 pp5 Total
A   100 33  45  67  88  333
B   20  34  46  68  44  212
C   59  35  47  69  45  255
D   23  36  48  70  46  223
E   23  37  49  71  47  227
F   11  38  50  72  48  219
G   45  39  51  73  49  257
```

i tried this code but no result

```
select pp1, pp2, pp3, pp4, pp5, sum (pp1, pp2,pp3,pp4,pp5,pp6) as total 
from tablepp
```

..... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove Sum it's a aggregate function

```
SELECT "ID", "pp1", "pp2", "pp3", "pp4", "pp5",("pp1"+"pp2"+"pp3"+"pp4"+"pp5") as Total
FROM TableName
```